# How can I build a tf which is required by gampping?

Tags: ros, navigation, kinect, gmapping, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finished base_link → odom tf like this

```
    map
     |
   odom
     |
 base_link
```

But in another required tf transform, it reads

> (the frame attached to incoming scans) → base_link
> usually a fixed value, broadcast periodically by a robot_state_publisher, or a tf static_transform_publisher.

(http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping)

I can not understand how to build tf: scan→ base_link , and depthimagine_to_laserscan(I use kinect) do not
provide any tf Transform.

And tf transforms in Turtlebot like this:

```
                                 map
                                  |
                                odom
                                  |
                              base_link
                                  |
                  ---------camera_rgb_frame-------
                  |               |              | 
    camera_depth_frame     camera_link   camera_rgb_optical_frame
                  |
    camera_depth_optical_frame
```

So, how can I combine **scan data** to base_link and broadcast this tf like turtlebot?

Some keywords like "camera_depth_frame", "camera_link"... Broadcasting them direct without any define or export?

And my kinect is fixed on the underpan, does it need a URDF file, or just use static_transform_publisher is fine?

Sincerely

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222956/how-can-i-build-a-tf-which-is-required-by-gampping?/) by [Bill Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/25401/bill-gates/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can simply use a [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) to build scan→ base_link tf.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bill Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/25401/bill-gates/) on 2015-12-22**:
But some keywords like "camera_depth_frame", "camera_link"...
Broadcasting them direct without any define or export? I set "false" as a default for "publish_tf" in ".../freenect_launch.launch".
Thanks.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-12-22**:
I am not sure I understand your question, but you can also use a static_transform_publisher to create a tf between your base_link and the kinect (following the example you posted, that would be "base_link -> camera_rgb_frame".

**Comment by [Bill Gates](https://answers.ros.org/users/25401/bill-gates/) on 2015-12-22**:
Thank you, let me give it a try.

**Comment by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) on 2015-12-23**:
i too am currently working on the same. I used the following command to provide a static transformation between the two
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher -0.27 0.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 base_link camera_link 100